# How to remove slot, created in Designer mode?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, qt-designer

I've created the button `cancelButton`. Then I've created function-slot `on_cancelButton_clicked()` for it using context menu item `Go to slot`. But, after a while, I've deleted this button (it wasn't longer needed), and tried to delete that function, but compiler gives error `undefined reference to <class_name>::on_cancelButton_clicked()`.

I've made cleanup of build folder (and removed it), checked for some lines in ui file that can point to this function, but i didn't found anything.

Comment: You haven't removed the declaration of `<class_name>::on_cancelButton_clicked()` from `header` file most probably!!

Comment: @Ammar Yes, thanks :) Pleace reply the question, I'll accept your response.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution is simple. I didn't remove the declaration of `<class_name>::on_cancelButton_clicked()` from header file. (by [Ammar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447144/ammar), posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082348/how-to-remove-slot-created-in-designer-mode#comment14510244_11082348))