# Qt Designer: How to remove slot from designer?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt-designer

Adding slot for a signal of a widget is easy: right click on it and select "go to slot". But how can I remove the slot created for a button (like `on_pushButton_clicked`) from the Qt designer.

Comment: your answer is here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082348/how-to-remove-slot-created-in-designer-mode#comment14510244_11082348

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to remove the declaration of `<class_name>::on_pushButton_clicked()` from header file.

Answer (score 0):

You can press View->Signal/Slot editor, then, a new window will be shown, simply remove the slots by pressings the minus button.